# Remove Regex from string PySpark Dataframe Column

Tags: python, regex, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to remove a regular expression from a column of strings in a pyspark dataframe

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Dog 10H03", "10H03"),
        ("Cat 09H24 eats rat", "09H24"),
        ("Mouse 09H45 runs away", "09H45"),
        ("Mouse 09H45 enters room", "09H45"),
    ],
    ["Animal", "Time"],
)
```

The timestamp, e.g. 10H03, is the regular expression that must be removed.

```
+--------------------+------------------+-----+
|              Animal| Animal_strip_time| Time|
+--------------------+------------------+-----+
|           Dog 10H03|              Dog |10H03|
|  Cat 09H24 eats rat|     Cat  eats rat|09H24|
|Mouse 09H45 runs ...|  Mouse  runs away|09H45|
|Mouse 09H45 enter...|Mouse  enters room|09H45|
+--------------------+------------------+-----+
```

The timestamp in the column `Time` might be different to the timestamp in the column `Animal`. Hence, it can not be used to match strings.

The regular expression should follow the pattern of XXHXX where X is a number between 0-9

Comment: If `time` might be different and cant be used, why do you include it in your question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the work :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("Animal_strip_time", F.regexp_replace("Animal", r"\d\dH\d\d", ""))

df.show()
+--------------------+-----+------------------+                                 
|              Animal| Time| Animal_strip_time|
+--------------------+-----+------------------+
|           Dog 10H03|10H03|              Dog |
|  Cat 09H24 eats rat|09H24|     Cat  eats rat|
|Mouse 09H45 runs ...|09H45|  Mouse  runs away|
|Mouse 09H45 enter...|09H45|Mouse  enters room|
+--------------------+-----+------------------+
```